# calling 2 functions from 2 different controller on one click

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controller say `cont_a` and `cont_b` which has  function `fun_a()` and `fun_b()` respectively.
I have a button inside `cont_a` and if I click on it it should call both function, and I have no idea from where to begin with.

Thank you.

Comment: Not nearly enough information given about these functions. Please show all relevant code and a better explanation of what they do

Comment: The function has only alert in it and it doesn't contains any complex code @charlietfl

Comment: What is the scope relationship between the two controllers?  Is the other controller on a parent scope, child scope, or sibling scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options, use a service or use an angular event

Service approach

```
app.service('funcService', function(){
   this.fun_a = function (){
      alert('fun_a')
   }
   this.fun_b = function (){
      alert('fun_b')
   }

}

app.controller('Ctrl_1' , function($scope,funcService){
    $scope.callBothFunctions = function(){
          funcService.fun_a();
          funcService.fun_b()
    }
});
app.controller('Ctrl_2' , function($scope,funcService){
    $scope.func_b = funcService.func_b;
});
```

Event approach

```
app.controller('Ctrl_1' , function($scope,$rootScope){
   $scope.fun_a = function (){
      alert('fun_a');
      $rootScope.$broadcast('call-fun_b');
   }
});
app.controller('Ctrl_2' , function($scope){
    $scope.fun_b = function (){
      alert('fun_b')
   }
   $scope.$on('call-fun_b', function(){
        $scope.fun_b();
   })
});
```

Beyond this, question is too vague to know what best approach is. Generally using services is best way to keep controller code lean